# Pass values between components Angular 2 - Not Parent/Child

Tags: angular, typescript

Just learning Angular and would like some design architecture advice.

If I have a search component that needs to feed a summary component with the results, without them necessarily being parent/child, what's the best architectural approach to doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: Read the documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service I know it says parent-child but it works for non parent-child relationship

Comment: This has been asked many times before, try to search first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular+communication+between+components

Comment: Thanks for all the help and other comments.  If you're coming to something new then having people explain what is contained in the docs is very helpful, whereas searching amongst previous questions is not.

Answer (score 0):

If your component isn't parent / children, use service for to share your data. I thinks is the best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use the parent-child relation.

But if you don't want to, there are several ways, including :

- Using a shared service in a shared module
- using a shared file (like `environment.ts`) to share your values
- use the built-in methods (for instance, `localStorage`) of browsers.

I think that the ranking goes something around

```
Parent/Child > Service > Shared file > Common methods
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are few approaches:

- Using Services(Most Recommended).
- Using Behavior Subjects from RxJS library.
- Using browser storage(session/local) but least recommended as prone
  to data security.

Comment: Thanks for the help