# Angular data communication to and from components

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a parent component (P1) and two child components(C1 and C2).
Both the child components have a primeng data-table which are editable.
I have two buttons on P1 : **fetch() and save()**.
**fetch()** calls the database to get the data.
I'm using a shared service to fetch data and pass it down to the components using BehaviorSubject.
My data object looks like:

```
export interface ParentObj { name: string; child1 : Child1[]; child2: Child2[]}
export interface Child1 { weight: number;}
export interface Child2 { code: string;}
```

Child components subscribe to the data from the shared service.
Now the issue is that the Child components also modify the data which they have.
So on click of **save()** on the P1, I am unable to get the latest modified values from the child components as I do not have any way of notifying P1 that C1 and/or C2 has changed the data.

Is there a way to accomplish the same so that I could notify the child components when the **save()** is called and it reflects in the **ParentObj**?.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455401/5346095

Comment: @Manu: Data is already passed from Parent to child but not the other way round as there is no means of communication like an event on the Child component.

Comment: you should try Using Behavior Subjects from RxJS library

Comment: try to use redux `ngrx-store` for state management and sharing data across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the `ViewChild` from `'@angular/core'` as there was no event trigger on the child components.
The parent can read the child attributes using the `@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;`
Reference: [Here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Child-to-Parent-Sharing-Data-via-ViewChild)

Answer (score 1):

You can use event emitter for this purpose AND this is most useful when communicating from child component to parent component.

Example:-

**P1 component:-**

```
<c1 (notifyParent)="notify(data)"></c1>
<c2 (notifyParent)="notify(data)"></c1>

notify(data) {
    console.log(data); //notify parent
}
```

**C1 component:-**

```
@Output() notifyParent= new EventEmitter();
```

and then

```
this.notifyParent.emit(data) //or notify with true value
```

**C2 component:-**

```
@Output() notifyParent= new EventEmitter();
```

and then

```
this.notifParent.emit(data) //or notify with true value
```